# Inequality for Subgaussian Norms and Lipschitz Functions

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, lipschitz-functions, orlicz-spaces

If I have a $L$-Lipschitz function $\psi \colon \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\psi(0) = 0$, and a random variable $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, is it true that

$$ \|\psi(X)\|^2_{\phi_2} \leq L^2 \sigma^2 \|Y\|^2_{\phi_2},$$

where $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $\| \cdot \|_{\phi_2}$ denotes the subgaussian norm?

I found a similar result which states
$$ | \mathbb{E}[\psi(X)^2] - \mathbb{E}[\psi(Z)^2] | \leq L^2 |\sigma^2 - \rho^2| $$
for another random variable $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \rho^2)$, but I don't see how to use this or if it is even helpful. I don't think I can set $Z$ to zero can I? And even if I could, I would be missing the term with the norm of the standard normal in the desired result... any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to follow directly from the definition of the Orlicz norm. By the Lipshitz condition $|\psi(X)| \le L |X|$. Hence, since $\phi_2$ is increasing,

$$
\| \psi(X) \|_{\phi_2 } = \inf \{ u> 0 : E \left[\phi_2\left( \frac{|\psi(X)|}{u} \right)\right] \le 1\} \le \inf \{ u> 0 : E \left[\phi_2\left( \frac{L| X|}{u} \right)\right] \le 1\} =  L\|X \|_{\phi_2 }.
$$
Replacing $X=\sigma Y$, where $Y$ is standard normal, we see $L\|X \|_{\phi_2 }=L\sigma \| Y \|_{\phi_2 }.$

Comment: Thank you! I think I just overcomplicated things...

Comment: No problem! The question at first had me thinking about an interesting problem: If two random variables satisfy $|X| \le |Y|$, then for any norm on random variables $\|\cdot\|$ is it true that $\|X\|  \le \|Y\|$? I could not come up with a proof of this stronger fact, in fact I think it might not hold for norms of the form $\|\cdot\| /(1+\|\cdot\|)$, but evidently it holds for Orlicz norms.